# How to break the loop in python

Tags: python, excel

I am new to python , some how I did my task , I getting blocked in the last step. I have number of time "if p['value'] == '0.04':" in FileA . I want to break the loop when it occurs second time. Because i have "0.04" 30 times in FileA. How to break it.

Code:

```
import glob,os
import sys
import json
import pathlib
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("Excel_resu", cell_overwrite_ok=True)

    def main(argv):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\New_Folder'):
                  for filename in files:
                    if "FileA.json" in filename:
                        FileA = (os.path.join(root,filename))

                    if "FileB.json" in filename:
                            FileB = (os.path.join(root, filename))

                            test(FileA, FileB)

    def test(FileA,FileA):

        count =0

        with open(FileA) as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for p in data:
                if p['value'] == '0.04':
                    print(p['Time'])
                    GetTime = (p['Time'])
                    with open(FileB) as json_file1:
                        data1 = json.load(json_file1)
                        for q in data1:
                            if q['Time'] == GetTime:
                                print(q['Gettar'])
                                resu = q['Gettar']
                                count = count+1
                                ws.write(count, 3, resu)
                                wb.save("Excel.xls")
```

Comment: why not have a second count in the if statement with an and, eg : if p["value"]== '0.04' and count==0:

Comment: That way program will go into the if loop only once

Comment: I tried to put the count and break the for loop. But the problem is It reset the excel column count. Hence it writes all resu in the same cell. Do you have any solution .

Comment: you want to break the for loop as in skip that iteration or you want to stop the execution of for loop altogether ??

Comment: Want to break the for loop .But as I have to lots of file "resu" has to write . It has to increment and write the data to excel

Comment: For example : the below code work perfectly. but it affect my writting to excel ....... with open(FileA) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        value_count = 0
        for p in data:
            if value_count => 1:
                break
            elif p['value'] == '0.04':
                value_count = value_count + 1
                print(p['Time'])
                GetTime = (p['Time'])
                with open(FileB) as json_file1:

Comment: kindly try the new code and rever back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the new information and our discussion try this code. It can raise one issue but try it out and let me know, don't forget to make relevant changes in the code,as in keys of dictionaries etc, they shouldn't be many

```
import glob,os
import sys
import json
import pathlib
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()


ws = wb.add_sheet("Excel_resu", cell_overwrite_ok=False)


count2=0


def main(argv):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\New_Folder'):
              for filename in files:
                if "FileA.json" in filename:
                    FileA= (os.path.join(root,filename))

                if "FileB.json" in filename:
                        FileB= (os.path.join(root, filename))
                        count2+=1
                        test(FileA,FileB,count2)

def test(FileA,FileB,count2):
    count=0

    with open(FileA) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data:
            #print (p)
            if p['EgoSpeed'] == '0.04' and count >=1:
                pass
            elif p['EgoSpeed'] == '0.04' and count ==0:
                #print(p['Time'])
                GetTime = (p['AdtfTime'])
                with open(FileB) as json_file1:
                    data1 = json.load(json_file1)
                    for q in data1:

                        #print(q)
                        if q['AdtfTime'] == GetTime:
                            #print(q['Target1_ForwardDist'])
                            res = q['Target1_ForwardDist']

                            cols=["B"]

                            #print(count)    
                            row=ws.row(count2)
                            for index,col in enumerate(cols):

                                row.write(index,res)
                            wb.save("Dilip_test.xls")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new count that checks for that value and breaks the for if it is comes a second time:

```
 with open(FileA) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        value_count = 0
        for p in data:
            if value_count => 1:
                break
            elif p['value'] == '0.04':
                value_count = value_count + 1
                print(p['Time'])
                GetTime = (p['Time'])
                with open(FileB) as json_file1:
                .....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At first i tried with counter and break. But then it affect function in excel "count" is reset to 0 . So it keep on writing in the same cell.                              count = count+1
                                ws.write(count, 3, resu)
                                wb.save("Excel.xls")

Comment: Why would it write to the same cell? It should brake the loop and end the code? Of course if you restart the code, it will reset the count to 0, but it would to that anyway...? 
You could check if p['value'] is 0.04 and if value_count is 1 or more and just pass, which would continue the for loop

If you have more code that you're not showing, then I can't help with that

Comment: yes thats problem , can you give me a pointer , Because of cout =0 value is overwriting, when I call another file. I like to take the value from different file and write it to Excell . But due to count=0 it write everytime in (0,3) . i want when another file compare it has to write in (1,3) ,(2,3)......(10,3)

Comment: Either a) start the program by finding the first empty cell and continuing from there or b) make a separate settings file that has the has count in memory and read/update the count there

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused but I think this should work for you, please try and revert back

```
import glob,os
import sys
import json
import pathlib
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("Excel_resu", cell_overwrite_ok=True)

    def main(argv):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\New_Folder'):
                  for filename in files:
                    if "FileA.json" in filename:
                        FileA = (os.path.join(root,filename))

                    if "FileB.json" in filename:
                            FileB = (os.path.join(root, filename))

                            test(FileA, FileB)

    def test(FileA,FileA):

        count =0

        with open(FileA) as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for p in data:
                if p['value'] == '0.04' and count>=1:

                    pass
                elif p["value"]=="0.04" and count==0:
                    print(p['Time'])
                    GetTime = (p['Time'])
                    with open(FileB) as json_file1:
                        data1 = json.load(json_file1)
                        for q in data1:
                            if q['Time'] == GetTime:
                                print(q['Gettar'])
                                resu = q['Gettar']
                                count = count+1
                                ws.write(count, 3, resu)
                                wb.save("Excel.xls")
```

Look at this example on what I meant by in comment:

```
count =0    

    def test(FileA,FileB,count):



        with open(FileA) as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for p in data:
                if p['value'] == '0.04' and count>=1:

                    pass
                elif p["value"]=="0.04" and count==0:
                    print(p['Time'])
                    GetTime = (p['Time'])
                    with open(FileB) as json_file1:
                        data1 = json.load(json_file1)
                        for q in data1:
                            if q['Time'] == GetTime:
                                print(q['Gettar'])
                                resu = q['Gettar']
                                count = count+1
                                ws.write(count, 3, resu)
                                wb.save("Excel.xls")
        return count     

    #assuming calling the function from here:
    for i in range(number_of_files):    
        count=test(FileA,FileB,count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .Problem is "ws.write(count, 3, resu)" , When the loop breaks it go "  count =0" and reset the count . I want count should be increament when it goes to next file . So that another data can be written into next cell . Because Now value from another file is owerwriting the previous value.

Comment: the loop isn't breaking we are just skipping a single iteration why will the count become zero ??

Comment: I am sure there is some more code at work here, whenever you call test it will give count zero as its define within the function

Comment: yes thats problem , can you give me a pointer , Because of cout =0 value is overwriting, when I call another file. I like to take the value from different file and write it to Excell . But due to count=0  it write everytime in (0,3) . i want when another file compare it has to write in (1,3) ,(2,3)......(10,3) .

Comment: define count initially and then pass it to the function, return the iterated value and change the count defined outside the function to refeed it for the next run

Comment: sharing an example

Comment: When I declare the variable in outside the function : I  have "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'buil' referenced before assignment" error .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176689/discussion-between-inder-and-user2965711).

Comment: I fix it by my self adding another counter in the main function . It works as what I want. Thanks for your great help and your valuable time. Thanks once again .

Comment: Sorry it didnt work. . can you check in the evening??